# C# Linq add element to list of object where condition is met

Tags: c#, linq

I have a player class

```
public class Player : Person
{
    public List<int> SetPoints;
}
```

And a game class

```
private List<Player> Players;

public Game(List<Player> players)
{
    Players = players;
}

public void Simulate()
{
    var winnerPoints = 6;
    var looserPoints = Tournament.Random.Next(0, 5);
    var winnerId = Players[Tournament.Random.Next(0, 1)].Id;

    Players.Where(p => p.Id == winnerId).Select(p => p.SetPoints).Add(winnerPoints);
}
```

The code demonstrates what im trying to accomplish but i cant access the SetPoints list for updating, in the selected player object. Can anyone point out what modification i need to make in order for this to work?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATED**

My goal was to add `winnerPoints` to SetPoints of one random `Player` object in `Players`, and `loserPoints` to the other (`Players` is always a list of two objects, provided by the constructor) thanks to maccettura i accomplished this by using `FirstOrDefault()`

```
    public void Simulate()
    {
        var winnerPoints = 6;
        var loserPoints = Tournament.Random.Next(0, 5);
        var winnerId = Players[Tournament.Random.Next(0, 1)].Id;

        Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == winnerId).SetPoints.Add(winnerPoints);
        Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id != winnerId).SetPoints.Add(loserPoints);
    }
```

Comment: You likely want `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Where().Select()`.  Also, `looserPoints` should probably be `loserPoints` (its a typo)

Comment: The `Select()` will return an `IEnumerable<List<int>>` not a `List<int>`.

Comment: @maccettura That should be an answer IMO

Comment: I can't use FirstOrDefault() as i must select a random of the two Player objects in the list. I tried adding .ToList() after Select() followed by .Add(winnerPoints) but i receive an error saying i cant convert from int (winnerPoints) to List<int> - however that should be possible in theory?

Comment: @MikeHawkins that makes no sense.  `FirstOrDefault()` is the same logic you have now (but working).  Also, there is nothing "random" about the code you have posted.  If there is some other requirement it needs to be included in the question.  Please see how to add a [MCVE]

Comment: If i use FirstOrDefault() ill always get the first object of the two in the sequence, however if i select by an Id property randomly chosen from either of the two objects it can be one or the other - how is that the same logic?

Comment: @MikeHawkins `First` and `FirstOrDefault` can take a lambda just like a `where` can (i.e. first that matches the criteria)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you want a single matching `Player` object:

The code you are using now does not do what you think it does:

```
Players.Where(p => p.Id == winnerId).Select(p => p.SetPoints)
```

What this is doing is looking for *all* matches on `winnerId`, then selecting *all* of the matching lists properties.  This results in an `IEnumerable<List<int>>`.

If you need just one `Player`, to do that you need to use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var player = Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == winnerId);
//Check if player is not null, then add
```

This will give you a `Player` as the return, or the `default(Player)` (null) if there is no match.

Now that you have the `Player` object you can access the `SetPoints` property and `Add()` from there.

### If you want all matching `Player` objects:

If you want *all* matching `Player` objects you just need to iterate over your `Where()` query results:

```
//Where() returns an IEnumerable<Player>
foreach(Player p in Players.Where(p => p.Id == winnerId))
{
    p.SetPoints.Add(winnerPoints);
}
```

Comment: @MikeHawkins I was going to reply to the parent question, but I will do it here.  Can you elaborate on the "random" thing you mentioned?  I wanna make sure I clear that up (if its still unclear)

Comment: It's clear to me now that you have explained that FIrstOrDefault() can be used with an expression to select a Player object (in this case, by Id) and then access the list of that object. See my updated question for the logic i tried to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `winnerId` is unique, it would be sufficient to find a single result using `FirstOrDefault`:

```
Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == winnerId)?.SetPoints.Add(winnerPoints);
```

For the case (or rather, another use case) that it isn't unique, and you actually *want* a list of results, you could use `ForEach()` after a call to `ToList()` (or a standard `foreach` loop):

```
Players.Where(p => p.Id == winnerId).ToList().ForEach(p => p.SetPoints.Add(winnerPoints));
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` can return `null`, which will crash on `.SetPoints`. If you know you should have a matching element, use `First(...)`, otherwise you should `null` check or use null propagation (`?.`).